# Losing JSON variable in a forloop

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to send variables to a PHP in a forloop. for some reason, the variable empties out. Heres the code:

```
function doSomething() {  
for (var i = 0; i < 1500; i+=15) { 
var div1 = "delete"+i;
var IDs = document.getElementById(div1).textContent;
  alert(IDs);
function deleteImages(){
    var params = {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://myserver.com/test.php',
        data: {ID: IDs},
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data) { 
            var div = document.getElementById('dvCSV');
            div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + data + "<br>";
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Fail, please contact webmaster ASAP");
        },
    };
  alert(JSON.stringify(params));
    $.ajax(params);
}
var time = 3000*i;
setTimeout(deleteImages, time); 
}
};
```

by the first `alert(IDs)`, the variable pops up on my screen. The problem is that when I `alert(JSON.stringify(params))`, the ID variable is empty.
Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: i (in var time) is not defined in the code above. Also, you're reading out an element's text 1500 times (in addition to having 1500 alert boxes)? Any reason you aren't putting the 'IDs' variable inside of the deleteImages() function? I'm very confused on what doSomething()'s loop does; this code needs some revising..

Comment: If I send more than 15 IDs to my PHP at a time, it fails, I have about 1500 IDs, So I made a forloop to go through all of them

Comment: So why deserved the downvotes?

Comment: @rsn i is the variable from the forloop

Comment: Ah I see, the formatting (or lack thereof) made it hard to see.

Answer (score 0):

by the time `deleteImages` runs on a timeout, you're no longer in `doSomething`'s scope, so the `IDs` var no longer exists.  `setTimeout` executes your function in the `window` scope.  one way to fix this is to create a closure by defining the function anonymously within the call to setTimeout, as such:

```
function doSomething() {  
  for (var i = 0; i < 1500; i+=15) { 
    var div1 = "delete"+i;
    var IDs = document.getElementById(div1).textContent;
    alert(IDs);
    var time = 3000*i;
    // create the function here so that IDs remains a relevant var
    setTimeout(function() {
      var params = {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://myserver.com/test.php',
        data: {ID: IDs},
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data) { 
            var div = document.getElementById('dvCSV');
            div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + data + "<br>";
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Fail, please contact webmaster ASAP");
        },
      };
      alert(JSON.stringify(params));
      $.ajax(params);
    }, time); 
  }
};
```

good luck!